# Let $G = (V,E)$ be a $3$-critical graph. Show that $G$ is a circle of odd length.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Let $G = (V,E)$ be a $3$-critical graph. Show that $G$ is a circle of odd length. **Hint**: Use the fact that $chrom(G) = 2$ iff $G$ is bipartite for $|V(G)| \ge 2$.

My attempt:

Since $G$ is $3$-critical, we know that for every $v \in V$, $chrom(G \setminus v) = 2$, thus, $G \setminus v \ $ is bipartite. Furthermore, a bipartite graph doesn't contain any odd cycles.

This feels like the right direction to go, but from here on, I think I cannot see the wood for the trees. The fact that $G \setminus v$ doesn't conntain any odd cycles shouldn't tell me anything about whether $G$ contains odd cycles or not, not even speaking about $G$ being an odd cycle itself. Could anybody tell me what I am missing?

Comment: What subgraphs cause a graph $G$ to have $\chi(G)>2$?

Comment: Well, odd cycles?

Comment: Okay, great. So $G$ has an odd cycle $C$. Suppose $v$ is a vertex of $G$ not on $C$. What is the chromatic number of $G-v$?

Comment: It should be the same chromatic number that we have for $C$, which is $3$.

Comment: ...but what did you assume about $G$ at the start?

Comment: That $G$ is $3$-critical, which means that $G-v$ should have the chromatic number $2$ actually.

Comment: ... hence, $G$ must be an odd cycle itself.

Comment: Great! Almost. You have shown that the vertices of $G$ all lie on the odd cycle $C$, but perhaps there are more edges in $C$. If you draw $C$ on paper and draw in another edge, what does that produce? What do you see?

Comment: Hmm, well, if I draw an odd cycle with $5$ vertices, for example, and I draw another edge between two of them, this produces another odd cycle, in this case the $K_3$.

Comment: Yes! Good example. In general, is there an expression for the sum of lengths of the two smaller cycles? (I didn't mean to 'answer' this question. I'm deleting it).

Comment: I'm not quite sure what kind of expression you are up to, maybe we haven't spoken about it in class.

Comment: Like in your example, with $C$ a $5$-cycle, you found that adding an edge had to make a triangle, but it also made a $4$-cycle. Those numbers add to $7$. You can also explore what happens on $7$ vertices to find a pattern. You can also proceed by contradiction, assuming both of the new cycles are of even length.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help! :-)

Answer (score 2):

A graph has chromatic number 2 if and only if it has no odd cycles. Since $G$ has chromatic number 3, it has an odd cycle. Pick such an odd cycle. But since it is 3-critical, for every edge $e$, the chromatic number of $G - e$ is $2$, which means $G - e$ has no odd cycles. But this means that every edge of $G$ must lie this odd cycle. But therefore $G$ itself is an odd cycle.